# Pentaho: Reading data from AWS S3: "Incorrect file system URI"

Tags: pentaho

I tried to read data from AWS S3 using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) but got the error message "Incorrect file system URI".

Conf: File folder address: s3:/Access Key:Secret Key@s3/oldsalesdata-tt/SalesforAWSandHadoop.csv

First step: Hadoop file input window => 'File' tab => pushing the button 'Show fle content' => file content is retreived correctly:

[image]

Second step: Hadoop file input window => 'Fields' tab => pushing the button 'Get Fields' => fileds are retreived correctly:

[image]

Third step: Hadoop file input window => 'Fields' tab => pushing the button 'Preview rows' => getting [the error message](https://fastupload.io/en/xTdgbMUT4bEi6TA/file) *"RepositoriesMeta - No repositories file found in the local directory: C:\Pentaho\pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428\data-integration\repositories.xml"*:

Fourth step: pushing the button 'Quick Launch' => getting [the error message](https://fastupload.io/en/JdW9O6aQ7c0CqUk/file) "No rows found":
[image]
[image]

The error message says that "Incorrect file system URI "s3://" in name "s3://oldsalesdata-tt", was expecting "s3:/Access Key:Secret Key@s3/s3". But when changing 's3' to 's3/s3' all the previews steps (first, second) also doesn't work, saying *"Couldn't find a valid file to work with."*

Any ideas what's wrong here?